# Are there Putty-like file explorers on Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec, unix, ssh, putty

Are there any applications out there like Putty with a Windows UI, like I can explore files, upload and edit without having to type in Unix commands, pure UI?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you need to run this on a Unix OS?

Answer (score 10):

### [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

> WinSCP is an open source free SFTP client, SCP client, FTPS client and FTP client for Windows. Its main function is file transfer between a local and a remote computer. Beyond this, WinSCP offers scripting and basic file manager functionality.

[image]

Comment: WinSCP is good enough that sometimes I long for a unix version of it

Comment: @Randolf Richardson I think that the 'Unix' tag was only referring to Unix commands. I believe that he is using Windows, but let's wait for an answer..

Comment: "with a windows UI" will be good enough.

Comment: @Earlz: sshfs, and the SFTP support in GNOME and KDE.

Comment: it is a Unix server that I am connecting to and need to upload, download and modify files there. I am looking for a Windows UI that help me doing all that without a need to learn all these UNIX commands.

Comment: I am currently using windows XP

Answer (score 2):

*If you're using a **Unix/Linux Operating System** (your Question didn't indicate which OS you're using), then this answer applies (I've also provided a separate answer in case you need this for a Windows OS).*

By "like putty" I assume you mean a text-mode interface.  If that's the case, then this application may work quite well for you (especially if you're already familiar with FAR Manager and/or Norton Commander):

Midnight Commander (free and open source)
  http://www.midnight-commander.org/

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

*If you're using the **Windows Operating System** (your Question didn't indicate which OS you're using), then this answer applies (I've also provided a separate answer in case you need this for a Unix/Linux OS).*

By "like putty" I assume you mean a text-mode interface.  If that's the case, then this application may work quite well for you (especially if you're already familiar with Midnight Commander and/or Norton Commander):

FAR Manager (free and open-source)
  http://www.farmanager.com/

This is a native Windows application that utilizes text mode.  It is available as a native 32-bit or native 64-bit application.

[image]

Comment: You can also get a WinSCP plug-in for the FAR Manager that will let you access a Unix/Linux system via SFTP/SCP very much like you'd access FTP or a local hard drive:  http://www.winscp.net/eng/docs/far

Answer (score 0):

[NexusFile](http://www.xiles.net/) perhaps? Depends on what you're asking for.

[image]